# How can I write unit tests against code that uses matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-unittest

I'm working on a python (2.7) program that produce a lot of different matplotlib figure (the data are not random). I'm willing to implement some test (using unittest) to be sure that the generated figures are correct. For instance, I store the expected figure (data or image) in some place, I run my function and compare the result with the reference. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In my [experience](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/), image comparison tests end up bring more trouble than they are worth. This is especially the case if you want to run continuous integration across multiple systems (like TravisCI) that may have slightly different fonts or available drawing backends. It can be a lot of work to keep the tests passing even when the functions work perfectly correctly. Furthermore, testing this way requires keeping images in your git repository, which can quickly lead to repository bloat if you're changing the code often.

A better approach in my opinion is to (1) assume matplotlib is going to actually draw the figure correctly, and (2) run numerical tests against the data returned by the plotting functions. (You can also always find this data inside the `Axes` object if you know where to look.)

For example, say you want to test a simple function like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot_square(x, y):
    y_squared = np.square(y)
    return plt.plot(x, y_squared)
```

Your unit test might then look like

```
def test_plot_square1():
    x, y = [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]
    line, = plot_square(x, y)
    x_plot, y_plot = line.get_xydata().T
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(y_plot, np.square(y))
```

Or, equivalently,

```
def test_plot_square2():
    f, ax = plt.subplots()
    x, y = [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]
    plot_square(x, y)
    x_plot, y_plot = ax.lines[0].get_xydata().T
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(y_plot, np.square(y))
```

Comment: With your solution, you need to return the result of plot. Is there a way to do the same thing without having to return it ? By "catching" the fig ? My plot functions "return" void for now, if it's the only way I can change but I'd like not to.

Comment: Look at the second example, it shows how you can introspect the axes object to find all of the data that is used to draw the plot within it.

Comment: @mwaskom Any experience running tests against a mpl.collection you added explicitly? e.g. `ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(...))`?

Comment: I was using `plt.scatter` and found my data in `ax.collections[0].get_offsets()` instead of `ax.lines[0].get_xydata()`.

Answer (score 22):

You can also use [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to mock `matplotlib.pyplot` and check that appropriate calls with appropriate arguments are made to it. Let's say you have a `plot_data(data)` function inside `module.py` (say it lives in `package/src/`) that you want to test and which looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_data(x, y, title):
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

In order to test this function in your `test_module.py` file you need to:

```
import numpy as np

from unittest import mock
import package.src.module as my_module  # Specify path to your module.py


@mock.patch("%s.my_module.plt" % __name__)
def test_module(mock_plt):
    x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x)
    my_module.plot_data(x, y, "my title")

    # Assert plt.title has been called with expected arg
    mock_plt.title.assert_called_once_with("my title")

    # Assert plt.figure got called
    assert mock_plt.figure.called
```

This checks if a `title` method is called with an argument `my title` and that the `figure` method is invoked inside `plot_data` on the `plt` object.

More detailed explanation:

The `@mock.patch("module.plt")` decorator "patches" the `plt` module imported inside `module.py` and injects it as a `mock` object (`mock_plt`) to the `test_module` as a parameter. This mock object (passed as `mock_plt`) can be now used inside our test to record everything that `plot_data` (function we're testing) does to `plt` - that's because all the calls made to `plt` by `plot_data` are now going to be made on our mock object instead.

Also, apart from [assert_called_once_with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once_with) you might want to use other, similar methods such as [assert_not_called](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_not_called), [assert_called_once](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once) etc.

Comment: This is my preferred approach. Also, it's important to note that if your code unpacks any calls to `plt` e.g. `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`, when testing you can manually monkey-patch `plt.subplots` to return as many `MagicMock`s as expected, e.g. `mock_plt.subplots.return_value = (MagicMock(), MagicMock())` before testing the code.

Answer (score 16):

Matplotlib has a [testing infrastructure](http://matplotlib.org/devel/testing.html). For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.testing.decorators import image_comparison
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@image_comparison(baseline_images=['spines_axes_positions'])
def test_spines_axes_positions():
    # SF bug 2852168
    fig = plt.figure()
    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
    y = 2*np.sin(x)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.set_title('centered spines')
    ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.spines['right'].set_position(('axes',0.1))
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('right')
    ax.spines['top'].set_position(('axes',0.25))
    ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('none')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('none')
```

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/devel/testing.html#writing-an-image-comparison-test):

> The first time this test is run, there will be no baseline image to
>   compare against, so the test will fail. Copy the output images (in
>   this case result_images/test_category/spines_axes_positions.*) to the
>   correct subdirectory of baseline_images tree in the source directory
>   (in this case lib/matplotlib/tests/baseline_images/test_category). When rerunning the tests, they should now pass.

Comment: I've tried your way and I got an Error. In matplotlib.testing.decorators there is an "import matplotlib.tests" that produce an ImportError : No module named tests.

I've done some research and indeed there is no tests module in my matplolib files and the documentation say quiet few about it. Does someone knows how to solve it ?

Comment: Looks like this way is deprecated "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
The ImageComparisonTest class was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.0 and will be removed in 3.2.
  @image_comparison(baseline_images=['spines_axes_positions'])"