# Testing event handling and picking with matplotlib

Tags: python, unit-testing, matplotlib, testing

As per subject, how to write tests for functions that deal with [pick event handling](https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) in matplotlib?

In particular, given the following minimum working example, how to write a test that would offer 100% coverage?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onpick(event):
    ind = event.ind
    print('you clicked on point(s):', ind)

def attach_handler_to_figure(figure):
    figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

def main():
    plt.ion()
    x, y, c, s = np.random.rand(4, 100)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(x, y, 100*s, c, picker=True)
    attach_handler_to_figure(fig)

main()
```

The critical part is for me writing tests for the functions `onpick` and `attach_handler_to_figure`. Regarding the plotting I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27950953) to be satisfying!

**MORE INFO:** I am not after a way of testing console output. What I am after are test functions, some sort of `test_onpick` and `test_attach_handler_to_figure` and `test_main` (well, in main the challenge is testing the line `attach_handler_to_figure(fig)`), that can be used by [pytest](https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) or any other testing framework.

Comment: Is [Python: Write unittest for console print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767627/python-write-unittest-for-console-print) what you're looking for?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Not really, I'm after a way of simulating the click! But thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course mock up a pick event. In the following I modified `onpick` to actually return someting. In order to test console output see [Python: Write unittest for console print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767627/python-write-unittest-for-console-print) instead.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onpick(event):
    ind = event.ind
    print('you clicked on point(s):', ind)
    return ind

def attach_handler_to_figure(figure):
    figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

def main():
    #plt.ion()
    x, y, c, s = np.random.rand(4, 100)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(x, y, 100*s, c, picker=True)
    attach_handler_to_figure(fig)


def test_onpick():
    from unittest.mock import Mock

    main()

    event = Mock()
    event.ind = [2]

    ret = onpick(event)
    print(ret)
    assert ret == [2]

test_onpick()
```

Comment: Thank you for a great answer! The mock event is exactly the piece I was missing.