# How to get arrow directions (i.e. U and V) in a matplotlib.pyplot.quiver plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if there is any way to get the arrow directions (i.e. `U` and `V`) using the `Axes` object after a [`matplotlib.pyplot.quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) is plotted. For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.quiver(X=..., Y=..., U=..., V=...)
ax.collections[0].something_that_returns_UV?
```

I know that `ax.collections[0].get_offsets()` would return the `X` and `Y` values, but I am interested in the `U` and `V` values instead.

**Use case:** automated testing of plots ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27950953/2099607)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection created by `ax.quiverkey` is of type [`matplotlib.quiver.Quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.quiver.Quiver.html). You can obtain `X`, `Y`, `U` and `V` directly as `ax.collections[0].X` etc.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2), np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, .2))
U = np.cos(X)
V = np.sin(Y)
fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
Q = ax.quiver(X, Y, U, V)

print('X:', ax.collections[0].X)
print('Y:', ax.collections[0].Y)
print('U:', ax.collections[0].U)
print('V:', ax.collections[0].V)
```

Comment: Ah, how silly of me, as I searched a lot and didn't find it! I thought a function like `get_offsets` should handle that. Thanks a lot!